# Handling Datetime with decimal '2010-02-14 20:18:58.313000000'

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In SQL Server I have some textual data in varchar fields I am trying to convert to datetime's.  The funny thing is this data at some point was in a datetime field, exported to flat file, and now I am reimporting it.

The problem is it is in this format `2010-02-14 20:18:58.313000000` and the conversion to datetime fails.  I have no idea how it ended up like this when it was originally extracted from a datetime column.  Basically a table was exported to a flat file by someone else.  The original table was lost.  I am reimporting back from the flatfile.

I could just drop the decimal but this would be like throwing out some of the data.  I'd like to maintain as much precision as possible.

How can I import this data from the varchar column back into a datetime column and preserve as much accuracy as possible?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, it casts with no problems once I throw out the trailing zeros past the first 3 decimals:

`select cast( left('2010-02-14 20:18:58.313000000',23) as datetime)`